# PHP: Return one of several arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a result that looks like this when I do a print_r($array);

```
(
    [0] => 96
    [1] => 95
    [2] => 94
)
Array
(
    [0] => 96
    [1] => 95
    [2] => 94
)
Array
(
    [0] => 96
    [1] => 95
    [2] => 94
)
```

How can I simply return something like "96,95,94"? And not return all 3 duplicate instances?

Thanks

Comment: Either that's the output of three `print_r()` calls with the first one being strangely headless, or you're not pasting the real output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_r($array[0])
```

If you have 3 repeated Arrays just use the first one.

Comment: If I do that, I get 959595.  :-(

Comment: @Scott please read @BoltClock's comment. If you have a multi-dimensional array (like tagged) and the result set is somewhat similar to what you pasted, you're good to go. Else you're calling `print_r` 3 times.

Comment: I checked and it's not doing print_r 3 times. argh. not sure what's going on.

Comment: Hmm. wait.. I think I am doing print_r 3 times. argh.